# Compatible version of Scala for Spark 2.4.2 & EMR 5.24.1

Tags: apache-spark

What Scala version should I use to compile/build with Spark 2.4.2? I tried with Scala 2.12 and got the below error message.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)[Ljava/lang/Object;

Any input is really appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon checking, 2.11.12 looks to be the scala version on EMR.
It worked for us.